# Is there are a way to determine process stages from inside a library

Tags: c++, initialization

For safety reasons, a library I am working on has to determine owning process stages. Precise determination is not required but something like before/after main, before/after multithreading is enabled?

Something like std::atexit but for the startup?

The best idea I have is to create a class that will set a mark and statically initialize it with the highest possible init priority. I hope there are some commonly used means.

```
#include <iostream>

namespace test {
static bool flag;
class Check {
 public:
  Check(char const* name) : name_(name), flag_val_(flag) {}

  void Print() {
    std::cout << name_ << ": flag: " << flag_val_ << "\n";
  }
 private:
  char const* name_;
  bool flag_val_;
};
class Set {
 public:
  Set() {
    flag = true;
  }
};
static Check late_check __attribute__((init_priority(10000))) ("late check");
static Set set __attribute__((init_priority(2000)));
static Check early_check __attribute__((init_priority(1000))) ("early check");
}  // namespace test

int main(int, char**) {
  test::early_check.Print();
  test::late_check.Print();
  return 0;
}
```

Update: it seems that clarification is necessary I do not need to impose any changes on any library initialization. All I have to do different initialization steps depending upon whether main() is already called. And it does not have to be precise I am ok to know that the main is about to be called.

I will have a "Set" class from above setting the static with max init-priority then My App constructor will do different things depending upon flag its value

```
App.h:
------
class App { public: App(); ...};

App.cpp:
--------
static bool flag;

class Set { Set() { flag = true; }};

static Set set __attribute__((init_priority(65535)));

App::App() { if (flag) DoLateInit() else DoEarlyInit(); }

Client1.cpp:
-----------
static App myStaticApp;


Client2.cpp:
------------
App* myDynamicApp = new App;
```

Update2:

1. It seems that the only viable solution was provided in the comments by @johnfilleau: make the library user aware of the requirement to execute the function in question during initialization.
2. The alternative is to add more mutexes and a few atomics to enforce the safe behavior independently of the client app actions. This looked like an overkill initially but after the discussion, it seems like a fair trade.

Comment: My project does this: `int main_started = 0; int main_finished = 0;` and  `int main() { main_started = 1; /*...*/ main_finished = 1; }`.  We use it for developer diagnostics for when things go awry, rather than program logic.  (The C++ part of the project is about 50 million lines of C++ code.)

Comment: When I need to do something that I don't want to put into a global constructor, but I want it to happen before main() --  I just put it into the first line of main().

Comment: Related? [What if two programs did this?](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20050607-00/?p=35413)

Comment: ISorry I am developing a library and I have no control over what is in the main.

Comment: What if two libraries (yours and somebody else's) both perform this magic process that will give them each the highest possible init priority? Who wins? Who should win?

Comment: > "ISorry I am developing a library and I have no control over what is in the main"  -- can't your library have a method that main() is required to call?  Or is the library some kind of injection / hook where the process doesn't know about you?

Comment: There are no "stages". `main` is just a function like any other. It doesn't even have to exist in any given program. Multithreading isn't enabled as a separate step, etc etc etc. In short you have an XY problem.

Comment: @Dave S To use the library main should call a function. The library is using static constructors and the problem is how to deal with the case where the function is not called. I have a bunch of static constructors created before the main and then I have another bunch of static constructors originating from explicit calls to dlopen() all I want is to make sure that the latter bunch to be left in a sort of passive state.

Comment: You probably should ask a question (maybe a new one) about the problem you describe in the comment above. You should expand a bit on it, explaining why you have two bunches of static constructors and what is that function that needs to be called.

Answer (score 0):

### How do I force my library to jump to the start of initialization order?

You can't.

Assume there is some magic technique by which your library can jump to the front of the initialization priority and jump to the end of deinitialization priority.

If your library has access to this magic technique, then you must assume that other libraries have access to the same magic technique.

If two libraries both try to jump to the start of initialization priority, then who wins?

This is an example of what Raymond Chen calls the ["What if two programs did this?" problem](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20050607-00/?p=35413).

### Okay, so how do I solve it?

You solve this problem by clearly defining requirements:

- What is the responsibility of your library?
- What is the responsibility of a program that uses your library?

If your library has some logic that must happen before anything else in the program, then the **best** you can do is the following:

### Communicate your library's requirements to your users, and require that your users adhere to that requirement

1. Clearly communicate to the users of your library that it has timing requirements

   1. To be initialized before "something else" happens (before any other static initialization, before any threads are launched, before any calls to competing library Foobar, etc.)
   2. To be cleaned up after "something else" happens
2. Give the users of your library the means by which they can initialize/deinitialize your library

   1. You **may** give users a "common" setup option that lazy-initializes your library, which they can use in the 90% of cases where this is fine
   2. You **must** give users a more bespoke way to init/cleanup your library (perhaps an explicit global "setup" method, perhaps you return a handle that cleans up the library on destruction)

Whatever you do, you must communicate these requirements to your library users, and **the best you can do** is to trust that they follow the rules.

### "For Safety Reasons"

If your library truly has to start at a specific point in time "For Safety Reasons", then it's especially important that you do not hide these reasons and requirements from users.

Comment: Sorry it is not about jumping in the order of initialization. I clarified my question.